# How to force recalculation of dependent parameter values in function argument when non-default dependency is passed?

Tags: python, function, arguments, default-arguments

Let's say I have 3 variables & a function `func`:

```
a=1;b=1;c=1
def func(a=a,b=b,c=b/a):
    print(a,b,c)
```

To my surprise, `func(b=2)` produces an output:

```
1 2 1.0
```

Why is `c` not `b/a`, ie not `2/1=2`?

How can I make the function recalculate the `c` when called, if either non-default `a` or `b` (ie either of them doesn't equal `1`) is passed?

Comment: I am open to a better question title if you can suggest one.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to c have a default value when nothing is passed, make c=None in functional argument and set default value inside function when no value of c is passed

```
a=1;b=1;c=1
def func(a=a,b=b,c=None):
    c = c if c is not None else b/a
    print(a,b,c)

Note: earlier solution fail when c=0 so updated as suggested by @MisterMiyagi
```

Comment: Thank you. Can confirm that this does indeed work if `c` is a number initially (tried with 0 and 1). Could you elaborate on how the `if c` bit works? I notice that this method fails if `c` is initially set to the value `False`, but this is quite a special case.

Comment: this answer is based on if c is of type int. [how `if c` work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) , this only fails when you set c to True not False as then it provide output True for c. Note answer based on all argument is of type int

Comment: This will fail when passing in ``c=0``, e.g. ``func(1, 2, 0)``. The check should explicitly test ``... if c is not None else ...``

Comment: @MisterMiyagi updaed solution